# Execute function at special time using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I write task manager, and i want to create bot, which must send message to user (maybe user's email or social account). 
I want to user can be able choose task and set time, when bot should send message to him.
My proble is that I don't know what i can user for it, I use django framework, and now i think that celery can help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery might be a bit heavy to start with.

You can try the [django_cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) to schedule your email tasks or other cron jobs that need to run at a specific time.

It's quite easy to set up following [its documentation](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: Tnx, maybe that's what I need.

Comment: And... Help me once more, how to set your answer like answer of topic?

Comment: Yeah, give it a try. 
Ah, I don’t think I set this up. I just searched the topic and answered some questions. Maybe search is the first step?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I might be misunderstood. If you are looking for accepting an answer, you can try follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).   To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.